# Spring Cloud Service Registers with Discovery Server but then un-registers and stops

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud, microservices

Nutshell explanation:
Build a very basic Eureka Discovery server spring boot 2.0.4.  Also created a basic Eureka service that uses Eureka discovery.  Start the discovery server and then start the service.  The service registers with the discovery server but then is immediately unregistered and stops.

Details Discovery Server Code:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

The Service: Note for this example I place the Controller within the main boot app.

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient  //Want it to registger with the discovery 
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController  //Obviously not a best practice just an example
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${spring.application.name")
    private String instance;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String message() {
        return "hello from " + instance;
    }

}
```

The service pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.skjenco</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The problem:
The Service will register but then unregistered.

```
2018-09-07 22:18:23.918  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2018-09-07 22:18:24.011  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2018-09-07 22:18:24.014  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
2018-09-07 22:18:24.016  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2018-09-07 22:18:24.019  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1536380304018 with initial instances count: 0
2018-09-07 22:18:24.022  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application service with eureka with status UP
2018-09-07 22:18:24.023  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1536380304023, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2018-09-07 22:18:24.025  INFO 9660 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SERVICE/325L:service:8081: registering service...
2018-09-07 22:18:24.041  INFO 9660 --- [  restartedMain] com.skjenco.service.ServiceApplication   : Started ServiceApplication in 4.053 seconds (JVM running for 4.947)
2018-09-07 22:18:24.046  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7fb5981d: startup date [Fri Sep 07 22:18:21 MDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@47583a40
2018-09-07 22:18:24.047  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application service with eureka with status DOWN
2018-09-07 22:18:24.047  WARN 9660 --- [      Thread-19] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1536380304047, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2018-09-07 22:18:24.049  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-09-07 22:18:24.051  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-09-07 22:18:24.052  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-09-07 22:18:24.053  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-09-07 22:18:24.055  WARN 9660 --- [      Thread-19] .s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

When debugging you can see the error when creating configuration bean.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:208) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:390) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:184) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9150922a.unregisterStatusChangeListener(<generated>) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:891) ~[eureka-client-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeDestroyMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.run(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:233) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.destroy(GenericScope.java:404) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.destroy(GenericScope.java:139) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:256) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:504) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1017) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) [spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

My work around is to not use the latest Spring boot initializr.  I Use 1.5.15 instead.

I would like to use Spring boot 2^ with spring cloud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice on the line of log:

```
2018-09-07 22:18:24.046  INFO 9660 --- [      Thread-19] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7fb5981d: startup date [Fri Sep 07 22:18:21 MDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@47583a40
```

Your application stop immediately after it started, and that does not relate to Discovery Client. Error logs at the bottom are just error when stop Discovery Client caused by application be stopped.

The root cause of this problem is your app is not a webapp because it doesn't have an **embedded Tomcat** inside it. That lead by lacking of Spring boot web on its classpath.

Resolution: Let add Spring boot web dependency on your **pom.xml** file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Cheers!

Comment: That was it.  Interesting that the latest 2.0.4 spring intializr omitted that.  Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue, after searching a lot I realized that I have added spring-boot-starter-tomcat, which is not required in case of spring-boot-starter-web is also there (which has tomcat in compiled dependency so it might be conflicting).